# UserPrincipal.GetGroups only fetches current domain Groups

Tags: .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I started off with this code to find all the groups that a user is in:

```
Using user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, name)

Dim groupList As AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = user.GetGroups
    For Each group As GroupPrincipal In groupList
        myUserGroupList.GroupList.Add(group.Name)
    Next
End Using

Return myUserGroupList
```

What I discovered was that this was not returning the groups from other domains, so I added the following:

```
If domain.ToUpper = "Domain1" Then
    Dim myDomainList As DomainConfiguration.DomainCollection = GetDomains()

    For Each DomainItem As DomainConfigElement In myDomainList
        If DomainItem.DomainName.ToUpper <> "Domain1" Then
            Try
                myUserGroupList.GroupList.Add(DomainItem.DomainName.ToUpper)
                Using OtherDomainContext As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainItem.DomainName, DomainItem.UserName, DomainItem.Password)
                    myUserGroupList.GroupList.Add("Using: " & DomainItem.DomainName.ToString)
                   Try
                      Dim NewGroupList As AccountManagement.PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = user.GetGroups(OtherDomainContext)
                      myUserGroupList.GroupList.Add(NewGroupList.ToString)
                          If NewGroupList IsNot Nothing Then
                              For Each newgroup As UserPrincipal In NewGroupList
                                  myUserGroupList.GroupList.Add(newgroup.Name)
                              Next
                          Else
                              myUserGroupList.GroupList.Add("No Groups for: " & DomainItem.DomainName.ToString)
                          End If
                   Catch ex As Exception
                      myUserGroupList.GroupList.Add("Other Context Ex: " & ex.ToString)
                   End Try

               End Using

           Catch ex As Exception
               myUserGroupList.GroupList.Add("unable to add: " & DomainItem.DomainName.ToString)
           End Try
       End If

    Next                  
End If
```

What is strange about this that, for every domain other than the current one, I get 1 entry for myUserGroupList with text of "PrincipalSearchResult`1". I feel like this should work, but I've been kicking it for quite a while now, and Microsoft claims this behavior is [By Design](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/658706/userprincipal-getgroups-method-not-returning-groups-from-other-domains). I'll try just about anything, but I was hoping to avoid the advapi32.dll . Thanks to anyone who answers.